# How to check for a certain pattern in Windows batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, findstr

I want to run something like this

```
C:\> mybatch.bat somefile.gz
```

or like this

```
C:\> mybatch.bat somefile.mps.gz
```

Inside the batch I want to check wether the argument ended with `.gz` or with `.mps.gz`.

This doesn't work

```
if findstr ".mps.gz" %1 (
    echo ".mps.gz file"
) else (
    echo ".gz file"
)
```

What is the right way to do this?

EDIT 1 (from https://stackoverflow.com/users/2128947/magoo):

```
set ZIP="C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7zFM.exe"

echo %1|findstr /i /L /e /C:".mps.gz">nul&if errorlevel 1 ( 
    echo ".gz only %1"
    %ZIP% %1
) else (
    echo ".mps.gz %1"
    call freempsgz2lpt.bat %1
)

pause -1
```

doesn't recognize the `.mps.gz` extension if I associate the batch file with extension `.gz` and double click in Windows Explorer. From commandline it works well.

EDIT 2:
I changed the proposal to

```
echo %1|findstr /i /L /e /C:".mps.gz""">nul&if errorlevel 1 ( ...
```

Now it works with file association in Windows Explorer but not on commandline. This is ok for me.

Comment: `echo %1|findstr /i /L /e /C:".mps.gz">nul&if errorlevel 1 (echo does not end .mps.gz) else (echo ends mps.gz)`

Comment: Works! I hoped it would look less cryptic and more clear like my code snippet but this seems not to be possible with windows batch :-( ... Thank You. And please post as solution to be marked by me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 echo %~1|findstr /i /L /e /C:".mps.gz">nul&if errorlevel 1 (echo does not end .mps.gz) else (echo ends mps.gz)
```

`findstr` is a utility that sets `errorlevel` = 1 if the string is not matched and 0 if matched.

Documentation : `findstr /?` from the prompt or [This tome](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8844873/2128947) or many examples.

In brief, `/I` means case-insensitive, `/L` is literal-match (as distinct from default `/R` - partial-regex) `/E` match at end of line, `/C:"stringtomatch"`

Comment: Maybe I was too fast. I edited the question.

Comment: Seems that your methodology delivers a quoted filename to the batch. Adding the `~` strips those enclosing quotes.

Comment: Wow, with %~1 it works for shell as well as association in Explorer. Perfect!